# How to change the font size of text in one cell jupyter lab?

Tags: python, html, css, font-size, jupyter-lab

I want to change the font size of a specific markdown cell in jupyter lab, and not the whole output. I will convert my project at the end into an html file.

I already tried this:

```css
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.a {
             font-size: 300%;
              }
        </style>
        <body>
            <div class="a">My text in here</div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

But this is not changing my text size after I run my cell under Markdown.
I also don't want to use  in order to not give a automatic number to that particular text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you want to change the font-size:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .a{                    //for class use .(class-name) 
            font-size: 300%;
        }
    </style>
</head>                        // all the styling is to be done inside the head tag.
<body>
    <div class="a">My text in here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am fine thank you Anurag, hope you are well too. I used your code: <br/> `<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .a{                                 
        font-size: 600%;
        }
     </style>
</head>                           
    <body>
        <div class="a">My text in here</div>
    </body> 
</html><br/>` How ever it doesn't change the font size. It's just showing me the default font-size.